# Checking command nested in conditional with shell

Tags: shell, git, make

I am currently trying to create a short and portable way to check if my working git directory is dirty and return T/F accordingly.
My ultimate goal is to incorporate this into a Makefile and I have implemented it as such:

```
GIT_DIRTY       := $(shell [[ -n $(git status -s) ]] && echo '\ dev')
```

My issue is that the `[[` operator is bash only, and as a requirement this Makefile needs to be able to run with `sh` only, no more fully featured shells. My hunch is that there is a way to accomplish this using `[` or `test`, but I am not sure how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GIT_DIRTY := $(shell [ -n "$(git status -s)" ] && echo '\ dev')
```

should work - but it doesn't, even though the command works fine in `sh`. It seems something in the `shell` function of `make` does not like the command.

Here's a workaround using a simpler command to give to `shell` and using a conditional function in `make` itself to do the rest of the job:

```
GIT_STATUS := $(shell git status -s)

GIT_DIRTY := $(if ${GIT_STATUS},DIRTY,CLEAN)

all:
    @echo ${GIT_DIRTY}
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, just as a heads up, the leading spaces in front of "DIRTY" and "CLEAN" also become part of the value of "GIT_DIRTY". This caused some issues for me since I was using "GIT_DIRTY" as a "-D" preprocessor argument for gcc and the space made GCC look for files called "DIRTY". To match my original question "DIRTY" and "CLEAN" should be "\ DIRTY" and "\ CLEAN".

Comment: Yes, that's right - I'll get rid of the spaces.